# What is the proper way to download the ink note image from Evernote server via http request(s)?

Tags: evernote

Evernote client app for Windows desktop allows one to create the ink notes which are internally stored as note's resources with a particular mime type: `application/vnd.evernote.ink`. The format of the resource is [known to not be](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/7943-linux-guinea-pigs/?page=2#comment-59366) shared with the developer community and no official Evernote apps for non-Windows platforms support this particular way to create the handwritten notes; such clients represent the existing ink notes (created via the Windows client) by read-only images which are [said](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/7943-linux-guinea-pigs/?page=2#comment-59368) to be possible to download from the Evernote server.

I was unable to find any further documentation or notes on how exactly to do this. The only source of knowledge available seems to be the [source code](https://github.com/baumgarr/nixnote2/blob/master/communication/communicationmanager.cpp#L978-L983) of [NixNote2](https://github.com/baumgarr/nixnote2), the unofficial open source Evernote client for Linux desktop. Here's the URL structure for such a request understood from the mentioned source code:

```
https://[service]/shard/[shardId]/res/[resourceGuid].ink?slice=[sliceNumber]
```

where `[service]` is the name of the Evernote service (either sandbox.evernote.com or www.evernote.com), `[shardId]` is the shard ID where the note is stored, `[resourceGuid]` is the GUID of the ink note's resource, the image for which one wishes to download via the request, `[sliceNumber]` is the number of the vertical stripe of the downloaded image i.e. the whole image is supposed to be downloaded via possibly more than one request.

My question is, how can one find out how many slices the ink note image might contain and hence, how many slices to request? In theory one can download the vertical stripes one by one until the cumulative height of the received slices reaches the height of the note image's resource but that would mean doing synchronous requests one by one which is not optimal performance-wise.

I also tried to do the request without the slices part at all. I do receive a reply for it but somehow the received data seems corrupt, I can't read a PNG image from it.

Comment: FWIW, when you don't add the slice parameter, you get back the resource in our `.ink` format (described in the discussion thread in the links you posted). Adding the slice parameter triggers the png rendering.

Comment: Thanks, I've come to think that's the case but it's good to have it confirmed.

Comment: I am not an expert on this but the relevant line from the source you quoted appears to be `int sliceCount = 1+((r->height-1)/600);`. Implies a slice is 600px relative to the `height` field in the resource.